# Solution approach for Common WebAPI Project and multiple Class Library Controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webapi

Requirement

1. I have a Web API project (running on the .NET Framework) which contains common functionalities implemented and it serve as a common for irrespective of different customers
2. There are 3 customers - `Customer1`, `Customer2`, `Customer3` (.NET framework class library controllers) which contain business logic respective to customer specific.

Example:

- `Customer1` has endpoints `GetDetails()`, `PostDetails()`
- `Customer2` has endpoints `GetDetails()`, `PostDetails()`, `GetOverViewDetails()`

**Note**: each customer projects are different class libraries, so the endpoint for each project can be similar, in the above example `GetDetails()`, `PostDetails()` endpoints exists in both the projects.

How to create a solution structure in a way that if I want to work on only `Customer1` specific, my Web API project should load only `Customer1` class library.

**Solutions attempted**

I tried to add the class library dll whenever it is required, but it is a manual process.

Is there a way to add the respective `Customer` class library based on any configuration?

Thanks